# Replace the filename in Windows '\\' path

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to remove the filename from a path created in C# (using Server.MapPath, which by default uses `\\`), like :

```
C:\\Foo\\Bar\\Baz\\file.js
```

My current regex looks to be somewhat working in [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) but in the real application it works just the opposite way :

```
\/[^\\]+$
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Try tagging the question correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're doing this in JS just do a `String.split` operation.

```
var path = "C:\\Foo\\Bar\\Baz\\file.js";
var separator = "\\";

function getFilenameFromPath(path, separator){
   var segmented = path.split(separator);
   return segmented[segmented.length-1];
}

console.log(getFilename(path, separator));
```

## The RegEx way...

By the way, the only thing wrong with your original RegEx was the leading \ and the missing /

```
 /[^\\]+$/
```

Would nails it. (the trailing `/g` on @JDwyers answer is to make it a global match, that's 
redundant for your use case.)

So...

```
path.match(/[^\\]+$/); // == "file.js"
```

Cheers

Comment: I can do it like this, but I was rather looking for a regex. Still proper answer. +1

Comment: @mike_hornbeck ^ see above.

Comment: @mike_hornbeck - the best thing about doing this as a function is the ease at which you can make it OS independent. The RegEx gets you out of dodge though, but I'd recommend avoiding RegEx when you can, simply for the sake of readability / maintainability.

Answer (score 3):

to keep with your regex:

```
var s = "C:\\Foo\\Bar\\Baz\\file.js";
var fileName = s.match(/[^​​​​​​\\]+$/​​​​​​​​​​​​g);
```

Comment: Note that the `g` is redundant here, the OP's original regex is correct except for the leading ` \ ` and the missing `/`

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the directory path, by removing the file name, thus:

```
var path = "C:\\Foo\\Bar\\Baz\\file.js";
var separator = "\\"; // make it OS agnostic.
var result="";

function getFilename(path, separator){
   var segmented = path.split(separator);
   for(var i=0; i<segmented.length-1;i++)
   {
        result+=segmented[i]+"\\\\";
   }
   return result;
}
alert(getFilename(path, separator));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Regular Expressions for this?  It is overkill when there is a function provided to do this in the `Path` class:

```
string dirName = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
```

There are also similar functions in the Path class to extract the filename, the extension, the path root, etc.

Comment: because I'm removing the filename with javascript in a phantomjs file, and I can't do it earlier.

Comment: You mean... you are trying to remove the filename in javascript?  If so, then this question should be tagged to javascript, not c#.  Otherwise, I'm totally not following you.